# Using Excel library get error

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to use the excel library for c#

In addition, use the following ref

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Now in order to do that I checked in the "reference manager" the line:
**"microsoft excel 15.0 object library"**.

when I am using any method from the excel lib I get the following error:

[image]

In Hebrew latters the massage tells us that "the class is not registered'

Maybe it is because the excel in my computer is not registered?

Need your help :(

Comment: Excel might not have installed properly...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because of your excel software. Excel has not been installed properly because of which the required dlls are not registered properly into the registry and causing this problem.

Please install/re-install the excel package and try it.

Comment: i have re install the office, still dosent work, is their any other way? maybe install the dll files dircetly?

Comment: Reinstalling Office should work – in theory. But in my experience it is almost impossible to completely “repair” Office if it is corrupted. I tried Office uninstall tools from MS, I tried registry cleaner, etc. Normally it is faster to reinstall the whole PC from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems on some PCs. It seems if MS Office is installed correctly all if fine. But if a user updated office or installed i.e. another version for testing and then removes it again the whole system becomes a mess. 
The easiest solution seems to be using late binding.
http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/InterDev/EarlyvsLateBinding.htm
In my experience that works with any computer independent of messy installations.
Personally I don’t like late binding so I use early binding on my developer PC and later I change all the variable declarations to “As Object”.